# Extract Salesforce live data in Azure SQL database

Tags: salesforce, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, etl, real-time-data

I have fetched data from Salesforce using Azure Data Factory into my Azure SQL database. I have fully setup linked services and datasets. I have fully checked the data which I fetched from Salesforce is coming right through my data factory pipelines.

Now I want my pipeline should automatically update the new data coming from Salesforce into my Azure SQL database. I do not know how I can achieve this. Can it be done using triggers or I would have to use different Azure service to fetch real time data?

Moreover I want to fetch data in such a way that if someone delete a row in any object it should get updated in my Azure SQL database as well.

I tried using upsert but it took 2 hours to just fetch 500 thousand rows of data.

Comment: What is the service tier of your Azure SQL Database?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using Azure Functions is a better approach in this scenario where you really need to keep an Azure SQL database in sync with Salesforce. Salesforce have available [Apex HTTP requests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm). Using [Azure Functions Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-azure-sql?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp), you can create an Azure Function that allows an HTTP request to be received and then execute CRUD operations on the Azure SQL database. You can apply one or more output bindings to an Azure Function with an HTTP trigger to insert/update data in an Azure SQL Database.